# Why we need React if jQuery is doing all things already

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, dom

What are main differences between ReactJS and jQuery? All the things are  already can be done by jQuery itself then why we need React? 
I searched in google and still am not clear about it.

Mostly it explains about the benefits in terms of "views", "components, "state", etc -- concepts that are unfamiliar for someone like myself who has only a superficial understanding of frameworks.

And where we have to use the React? Even for a small application (basic CRUP operation with some validation) we can use or it's really needed for a large application?

Comment: What jQuery doesn't do well is maintain state and provide a shadow DOM, two things React does very well, and mean you can write apps without building your own state manager and that run faster. https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/when-should-i-use-jquery-vs-react/191356/2

Comment: This question is too broad, and you'll only get opinions, so it's not really ideal for stack overflow. For me the main advantage of React is that it's extremely easy to maintain state and have it reflected in the DOM. With jQuery you have to have everything update the DOM manually, which gets hard to maintain as your applications scale

Comment: What you are mean by maintain state? could you please give some example or elabrate it?

Comment: You will not be able to learn React by discussing it in the stackoverflow comment section. If you are developing scalable web applications I would highly recommend you to look into one of the popular libraries such as React. You could take an online course such as this great one: https://www.udemy.com/react-2nd-edition/learn/v4/t/lecture/7517316?start=0

Comment: Okay. I love to learn new things and invest time on it. But I am asking why I should learn react.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery is a JavaScript library that simplifies HTML DOM tree manipulation, event handling, animation, and Ajax.

React allows you to update and render specific components when your data changes, which is great for development of single-page or mobile applications.

React is great for creating reusable sections of UI code, and layering them on top of each other so that you don't need to re-render the DOM as often. I have heard many people say that the more you need to update your DOM, the more you should lean towards React because it is built to treat your application's elements independently, which can make UI/UX seem a lot smoother. jQuery provides independent functions to your code to perform tasks, so it is great for making minor changes to the DOM, without having to restructure your whole UI.

Comment: You can find detailed info [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/forum/t/when-should-i-use-jquery-vs-react/191356/2) and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/550cke/what_does_react_allow_you_to_do_that_jquery/)